# Cannot install mysql2 in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I'm having problems installing mysql2. I've successfully installed it before. I have the latest Ruby version 2.0 and managed to install mysql2. Yesterday, I downgraded to Ruby 1.8.7 to run some old projects and test it. Then I uninstalled all ruby installation and return back to the latest one then my problem occurs. Here's the error

```
C:\DevKit>gem install mysql2 --no-ri --no-rdoc
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.16.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql
2-0.3.16 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/ext/mysq
l2/gem_make.out

C:\DevKit>
```

I also tried

```
gem install mysql2 --no-rdoc --no-ri -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\lib\" --with-mysql-include="C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\include"'
```

mkf log from mysql2 http://pastebin.com/RuSNKt3v

but no luck, same error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the content of the `mkmf.log` file?

Comment: I had not use Windows systems in very long time. Seems the problem is with: `error: unrecognized command line option '--with-mysql-include=C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\include'` if I remember right you should use something like: `--with-mysql-include=C://wamp//bin//mysql//mysql5.6.17//include` without the single quotes. Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I rather use JRuby instead of MRI (2.x) at windows, since i get a lot of compatibility errors due to a lack of native libraries, just remember to change your adapter to jdbc, in case you choose to change to JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

**C-Connector**

If you're installing the `mysql2` gem on a Windows system, you need to install the MYSQL C-Connector header files

We've [written a tutorial about this here](https://medium.com/p/a028f44d87f3)

---

The way to fix is relatively simple - you need to install the MYSQL C-Connector headers, and then reference them with your `mysql2` gem:

> 1. Install the MYSQL C-Connector headers
> 2. Run the `MYSQL2` gem installation again
> 3. Copy the `libmysql.dll` file to your ruby directory
> 4. Run your Rails installation with MYSQL2!

Firstly, you need to download & install the [MYSQL C-Connector headers](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/):

[image]

Please note how you should download the **32bit** version of the files (even if you use Win64). The reason is the mysql2 gem is `mingw32` only

Something else you need to know is that whilst you can install the files anywhere on your system, you need to keep the file path "space-free". This means you can't have *any* spaces in the directory path you create

--

Secondly, you then need to install the `mysql2` gem again, referencing the headers you've just installed:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector-path"'
```

This will allow you to reference the `mysql` connector path, which will provide the gem with the required "headers" it needs to install. This *should* work for you with any luck

--

Thirdly, you want to then copy the `libmysql.dll` file from your mysql header file path, to your `ruby/bin` directory:

[image]

This gives your system the ability to use the relative classes etc for Rails to run correctly. Once you've done this, you should be able to delete the MYSQL header files from your system :)